# Timestamp comparison query not actually filtering results

Tags: postgresql, timestamp

I'm having a really weird issue running a timestamp comparison query in my postgresql database.

I have a table called user (I know it's a terrible name) and we have a column named createdAt that's the type of timestamp with timezone. I should be able to run a query comparing against this column no problem. Yet, the WHERE in this clause (and the AND) don't seem to have any effect. I get back every single user from this table including ones with a null value in the createdAt column. I'm perplexed.

```
select * from "user"
where 'createdAt' >= '2017-08-01 23:25:53+00'
and 'createdAt' is not null
order by id desc;
```

EDIT:

relevant table structure and sample data

```
*** table columns ***

id serial primary key
createdAt timestamp with time zone
first_name text
last_name text

** sample data ***

id first_name last_name createdAt

1  john       smith     2018-09-21 02:53:42+00
2  james      smith     2018-09-19 00:27:14+00
```

EDIT: SOLVED

This was a weird issue but I wasn't getting any feedback from my where clause. The problem is the original devs named the columns camel cased which makes it necessary that any future queries referencing this column use the double quotes. Ended up having to say "user"."createdAt". That was a syntax issue on my part since I only ever name my columns snake case.

[Are PostgreSQL column names case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878932/are-postgresql-column-names-case-sensitive)

Comment: `'created_at'` is a string literal value, not a reference to a column. Try `user.createdAt`

Comment: ERROR:  column user.createdat does not exist
LINE 3: and "user".createdAt is not null
            ^
HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the column "user.createdAt".

Comment: That's what I get thrown unfortunately :/

Comment: please share the table structure with sample data.

Comment: Then try what the error message says to try!?

Comment: I did. Multiple, multiple times.

Comment: No, you didn't. The error message shows you used `"` in one place, but not the other. Use `user.createdAt` in all cases, not just half of them.

Comment: Ok, before I asked this question I did exactly that. Here, I'll show you the message.

Comment: select * from "user"
where "user.createdAt" >= '2017-08-01 23:25:53+00'
and "user.createdAt" is not null
order by id desc; 

ERROR:  column "user.createdAt" does not exist
LINE 2: where "user.createdAt" >= '2017-08-01 23:25:53+00'

Comment: select * from "user"
where "user".createdAt >= '2017-08-01 23:25:53+00'
and "user".createdAt is not null
order by id desc;

ERROR:  column user.createdat does not exist
LINE 2: where "user".createdAt >= '2017-08-01 23:25:53+00'
              ^
HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the column "user.createdAt".

Comment: is the where clause on other columns working?

Comment: So I figured it out and I'll edit the question to show the problem. It was a silly mistake on my part. (it ended up being "user"."createdAt"). I was able to figure it out by this stack overflow question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878932/are-postgresql-column-names-case-sensitive